# Do there exist kB-sized USB drives or SD cards?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, sd-card

I was wondering if there exist data storage devices with very small capacities like 8 or 16 kB.

The use for them would be transferring small files to and from a very sensitive offline computer. If your files are just under the size of your stick you can make sure no dangerous script is hidden inside your USB drive without having to do a check every time.

I know floppies exist but no modern computer supports these anymore.

I'm aware that there are probably better solutions for such safe file transfer, but I was also just wondering if such devices exist :) Can't find any on Google or eBay. The smallest one I've seen (and own) myself is a 16MB SD card.

Comment: If the computer is considered that "sensitive" USB storage devices should be disabled.

Comment: But there has to be a method for data transfer to and from it. What alternative is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you'll find anything with that small capacity. But as a workaround, you could format a regular USB drive so that the only partition is as small as you want, leaving the rest of the space unallocated.

Comment: Hmm, clever solution!

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the answer is no. Most manufacturers work to producing larger sizes and/or faster access and there's no market for 'tiny' storage devices.

Comment: This. Just recently I had trouble finding a 4 GB USB drive, no store seemed to have them at that small a capacity anymore.

Comment: Exactly: it would be unprofitable for manufacturers to make those small devices.

Comment: Do flash chips exist of this size? For in household devices maybe. Couldn't be too hard to make one yourself for the occasion :) But than I'd probably have to ask it in the Electrical Engineering SE.